# Firestore how to avoid displaying repeated field values (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying multiple documents that have the same field value. I do not want to output the same field twice.

```js
db.collection("books")
  .where("ItemType", "==", "Book")
  .orderBy("Author")
  .limit(100)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      let data = doc.data();
      let row = `<tr>
                    <td>${data.Author}</td> 
                 </tr>`;
      let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      table.innerHTML += row;
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
  });
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see the output, the fields are repeating. I don't want that to happen. How do I write my code in such a way that the field value only appears once, and if there is a repeated field value it should not display.

Comment: you need unique data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/13647574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, firebase doesn't have a "distinct" method.
(It would make your request much easier).

So you'll have to create an array and push the values in the loop to it.
And before adding its `row`, you should check if the current value already exists in the array, if not - add it, otherwise - skip.

```js
let authors = [];
db.collection("books")
  .where("ItemType", "==", "Book")
  .orderBy("Author")
  .limit(100)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      let data = doc.data();
      if (!authors.includes(data.Author)) {
        authors.push(data.Author);
        let row = `<tr><td>${data.Author}</td> </tr>`;
        let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        table.innerHTML += row;
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
  });
```

**Further suggestions:**
Since the table is the same element, You can define it once prior to the loop.
And you can put the  html directly instead of defining another variable (row).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your  help. I am getting this error :Error: TypeError: authors.include is not a function

Comment: Typo, try: includes*

Comment: that's a typo: authors.include will be authors.includes

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```js
let querySnapshot = [
  {
    Author: "A",
  },
  {
    Author: "B",
  },
  {
    Author: "C",
  },
  {
    Author: "D",
  },
  {
    Author: "A",
  },
  {
    Author: "B",
  },
  {
    Author: "C",
  },
  {
    Author: "A",
  },
];

let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
let allAuthers = querySnapshot
  .map(doc => doc.Author)
  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);

allAuthers.forEach((auther) => {
  table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${auther}</td></tr>`;
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```